# Can`t add pointer on object to the set

Tags: c++, templates, stl, set

Help me please.

"object.cpp":

```
bool OBJECT::operator== (const OBJECT &object) const
{
    return *this == object;
}

bool OBJECT::operator< (const OBJECT &object) const
{
    return this->m_numberOfObject < object.m_numberOfObject;
}
```

"other_object.h"

```
class other_object{
...
set<OBJECT*>* m_imitatedObjects
... }
```

"other_object.cpp"

`m_imitatedObjects.insert(pointer on some instance of class OBJECT)` -

raises error in runtime, as I think due to cmp function wasn`t defined properly.

What to do, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool OBJECT::operator== (const OBJECT &object) const
{
    return *this == object;
}
```

This function calls itself, causing a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). You should replace this function with whatever logic you want to use to tell if the two objects are equivalent.

Also, unless every `OBJECT` has a unique `m_numberOfObject` value, your `operator<` does not create a strict ordering. (Because neither of two objects with the same `m_numberOfObject` value but otherwise different will be less than the other.) This may cause your `set` to work differently from how you expect.

Comment: Thank you! now I see that is the problem. Tell me please how can I compare addresses of 2 instances, i need to know if they aren`t the same object

Comment: @spin_eight: If you really want to compare if they are literally, precisely the same object, you can use `return this == &object;`.

Comment: Sorry, again after adjustments I get:

`Error 21 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' to 'OBJECT *' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory 208`

Comment: @spin_eight: Think through the error message and figure out the problem. You have a const iterator to a tree of `_Mytree` and you are trying to use it as an `OBJECT *`.

Comment: I think I got it: i need to implement operators "<", "==" for pointers on instances of my class. I shall try it when will be on work. Have a nice day!